# Implementing a continuous integration pipeline in Jenkins using Zephyr, Bitbucket and Docker (Windows)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, zephyr-rtos

First post here, so ignore the newbie details about the question, the format will get better :)
My question has two questions: first it it doable? and second if eventually yes, any tips, recommendations on how to do this.
I have a software piece written in c in Zephyr RTOS (on a nrf 52840 board) and version-controlled in Bitbucket. Im trying to implement a Jenkins CI pipeline that fetch the code with newly pushed changes from Bitbucket and build it to check for errors and then report.
Now, to build that code in Zephyr I need a build environment and my solution is to run a docker container with zephyr image than is able to build that code and report back if everything looks good or not.
So basically my pipeline in jenkins will look like:

Fetch code from Bibucket.
run docker container with zephyr image that build the code
report back result to Jenkins.
What I have done so far:
Get bitbucket and Jenkins to connect. Have a container with zephyr image running that I got from docker hub. The image is zephyrprojectrtos/ci. Inside the container Im able to git clone my repos, still trying to figure out how to build the code and also if its possible to run something like a git clone inside a docker container but from a jenkinsfile. Any tips here? is it possible to pass a git clone command to a docker container from a jenkinsfile? or Do i have to include all (if possible) in the docker run command when running the container so it runs it and automatically checks out SW and build and report results back.
Im new to all this, Zephyr, Docker, Jenkins and I have no idea if this will work or not and if there a way around that is much simpler.
Thanks for your attention